# How to show a custom error text message if there is no data?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created my [first shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010560/my-first-r-shiny-app-my-plot-does-not-show/77010628#77010628) app and included tabpanels.
I am plotting filtered data.
Sometimes I come across cases that do not have anything to plot.
In my app the message appears:

`Error in renderPlot : object: graph_2 not found.`

The empty data frame is okay but the message is misleading for users.

[image]

It would be better if the warning says: "There is no data for plotting." How can I change the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/69563491/680068

Comment: And there is no way with working by text messages?

Comment: Please share a little code showing this issue. It will be easier to help.

Comment: And see the **shinyFeedback** and the **shinyvalidate** packages.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions may be to use `tryCatch` to display different message when there is an error:

```
tryCatch(stop("s"), error = function(e) "I'm instead of error")

[1] "I'm instead of error"
```

You could also check `req()` from `shiny` to stop executing code when some condition is not met, e.g.

```
req(exists("a"))
# some code
```

If the object `a` do not exists, then the code execution will be stopped and user won't see anything.

@Stéphane Laurent mentioned some packages in the comment, you may want also generally read about [validation in `shiny`](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-feedback.html)